# Implement i18n for standalone (Kafka consumer based) Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, internationalization

I am working on an application which is having a Kafka topic as an input point and a 3rd-party API as an output point. I need to implement the i18n for this application.
So basically I receive the input from the Kafka topic where I also get the locale in the message body. Now based on that locale I need to get some messages stored in the resource bundle. I have created the below files in the resources folder.

[image]

I also added the spring property `spring.messages.basename = i18n/messages`. But I am stuck on how to change the locale for each Kafka message.
What I want to do is, have a Kafka filter that gets triggered before the consumer. I want to set the spring locale in this Kafka filter class.

I show many articles and all talk about setting the locale using the `LocaleResolver` and `LocaleChangeInterceptor`. But as I receive input from Kafka topic instead of the web request. So those would not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing about the solution is really unique to Kafka. Use a `ResourceBundle`

```
// example values
String language = kafkaRecord.getLanugage();
String country = kafkaRecord.getCountry();

// Get i18n file
Locale l = new Locale(language, country);
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", l);
// Print the translated key
System.out.println(messages.getString(kafkaRecord.getEntry()));
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/quick.html

However, Kafka data typically isn't directly end-user facing, so the translation could probably be deferred to somewhere else, such as a GUI or a database query.

Comment: It looks good, but I have one problem with this approach. I will have to create Locale and ResourceBundle objects each time I need to get a message. I am looking for something like Spring managed beans and I can inject the locale once at the beginning of each request and then fetch the localized message.
Note: I need to fetch the localized message in many places in the code and I don't want to carry my locale object everywhere to fetch the locale-specific message.

Comment: You only need to create once. Then you can cache the ResourceBundle objects in a Hashmap. You can create Beans, sure. That's also not unique to Kafka